# Вставка значений в таблицу на событие создания другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

Всем здравствуйте!

Я встал в тупик из-за отсутствия опыта и знаний по mysql. Возможно ли реализовать следующую вещь: есть таблица `Tables(ID, TableName)`, возможно ли, чтобы при создании любой другой таблицы в таблицу `Tables` в поле `TableName` вставлялось название вновь созданной таблицы? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

<sub>Из сообщения от топикастера ниже:</sub>

Проблема в том, что априори приходится считать, что у меня есть полный доступ только к моей БД, доступ даже на чтение к системным таблицам у меня закрыт.

Comment: Внимание вопрос - нафига вам нужна эта табличка?О_о

Comment: И уж тем более запрещено будет вешать триггер на эту таблицу.

Comment: К примеру для реализации разграничения доступа не на уровне mysql, а собственно этот метод для упрощения этой реализации.

Comment: Зачем работать над велосипедом? Имхо, логичнее добиться нужного уровня доступа к своей базе. И к `information_schema` закрывать доступ со стороны админов - полная глупость.

Comment: Хорошо, вот фактически конкретная ситуация, вы хотите создать БД к сайту, хостер предоставляет вам только одного пользователя для подключения к БД, у которого есть все права, но только на нашу БД. Доступ к системным таблицам закрыт - по вполне понятным причинам, сама собой напрашивается мысль о том, что надо писать этот дурацкий велосипед. Но при этом возникает ситуация при которой нам придется выбирать нужные данные из достаточно большого множества, поэтому возникают дополнительные накладки по времени на пустом месте.

Comment: У нормального хостера `information_schema` доступна пользователям. Вы, вероятно, путаете `information_schema` с служебной БД `mysql`.

Comment: Задача сделать добавление название в таблицу сразу же после создания таблицы, не языком программирования а средствами MySQL. Как будто произошло событие - создание таблицы и на это событие есть обработчик вставка имени таблицы в таблицу Tables.

Comment: Такого события в MySQL не существует. Триггеры можно вешать только на изменение данных. Изменение структуры ними не отследишь.

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL уже есть служебная база с таблицей где есть список всех созданных таблиц `information_schema.TABLES`.

Если, конечно, речь идет о MySQL 5.x

Для версий ниже 5.0 список доступных таблиц можно получить через `SHOW TABLES`.